# an apk file that I can't decompile - reverse engineering android

Tags: android, apk

I'm a beginner android developer and I'm trying to decompile apps in order to learn how to develop. There are a few apps which I have tried to decompile but I didn't succeed, while other apps I succeeded to decompile. I have tried by apktool and dex2jar.

The most important thing:
I want to know how did they protect their apps againt reverse engineering. I would like to prevent reverse engineering to my apps in the same way.

thanks for help !!! :) sorry for bad English.

dex2jar and apktool show error:

```
C:\Users\helena\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\dex2jar>d2j-dex2jar.bat -f -o burger.jar c:/oldcomputer/h/burger.apk
dex2jar c:/oldcomputer/h/burger.apk -> burger.jar
com.googlecode.dex2jar.DexException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.opDataIn(DexFileReader.java:217)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:229)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.<init>(DexFileReader.java:240)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java:104)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:174)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:34)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.ZipExtractor.extract(ZipExtractor.java:31)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.readDex(DexFileReader.java:129)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.opDataIn(DexFileReader.java:213)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the APK is valid?  Use any "unzip" tool to examine the file.

Comment: `I'm trying to decompile apps in order to learning how to develop` This isn't the right way to learn how to develop.

Comment: better study open-source apps or tutorials!

Comment: If you truly want to learn how to develop, the right way is to start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: You cannot prevent reverse engineering, you can only make it harder.

Comment: @fadden , I changed the file to .zip and tried to open it, I got error: !   C:\oldcomputer\h\burger.zip: Unexpected end of archive. ligi, andrew, , I'm learning tutorials too. I said I want to know how they protected their apk.

Comment: Apparently the APK's zip file structure is corrupt.  Most likely this is an accident (such as a truncated file from an interrupted download or copy off the device), but perhaps it is *strategically corrupt* in a way expected not to trouble Android's zip file code, but known to disrupt common tools.  It wouldn't be the first time in the history of computing someone tried something like that, but it's always risky as a small implementation change in Android could end up breaking the ability to install or run the overly-clever APK even on authorized devices.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for your help, do you know how to do it? to strategically corrupt the file?